# Stange values after BigDecimal initialization

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying to initialize a HashMap in the foolowing way:

```
HashMap<BigDecimal,BigDecimal> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap .put(new BigDecimal(1.7), new BigDecimal(1.5));
myMap .put(new BigDecimal(3.3), new BigDecimal(3));
myMap .put(new BigDecimal(5), new BigDecimal(4.5));
myMap .put(new BigDecimal(6.6), new BigDecimal(6));
myMap .put(new BigDecimal(11), new BigDecimal(10));
myMap .put(new BigDecimal(16.5), new BigDecimal(15));
```

but tha value above insert are change in the following wang:

```
1.7 becomes 1.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
3.3 becomes 3.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
6.6 becomes 6.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
```

Why is happening this?

Comment: How are you getting those "wrong" values? What are you doing to inspect / print them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` static method: this will initialize the `BigDecimal` from string representation of the double number which is what you need.

Comment: Cute, plus one, but I prefer the faster if a little more involved `MathContext`

Comment: It is better to use the constructor new BigDecimal(String).

`System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.9999999999999999"));`
`System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.99999999999999999));`

outputs on my machine
1.9999999999999999
2.0
Also valueOf uses the String constructor, so the String can as well be provided directly...

Answer (score 2):

`1.7` etc. is a **floating point double literal**. 1.7 cannot be represented exactly as a `double`.

Its closest approximation to 1.7 is being passed to the `BigDecimal` constructor. And `BigDecimal` is capable of representing that imprecision so giving the observed effect.

`1.5` is a *dyadic rational* and so *can* be represented exactly.

One remedy is to use the `BigDecimal` constructor that takes a `double` along with a `MathContext` object: this allows you to control the rounding behaviour.

Another remedy is to use `BigDecimal.valueOf(1.7)`. Internally this will exploit conversion via a string. Although tractable, it is computationally expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the [constructor which takes a double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) , but the with [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29)

as per doc for the double constructor:

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to initialize a HashMap using BigDecimal.

```
    HashMap<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.7), BigDecimal.valueOf(1.5));
    myMap.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.3), BigDecimal.valueOf(3));
    myMap.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), BigDecimal.valueOf(4.5));
    myMap.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(6.6), BigDecimal.valueOf(6));
    myMap.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(11), BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
    myMap.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(16.5), BigDecimal.valueOf(15));
    Set set1 = myMap.entrySet();
    Iterator it1 = set1.iterator();
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry meEntry = (Map.Entry) it1.next();
        System.out.println("key is: " + meEntry.getKey() + " & Value is: " + meEntry.getValue());

    }
```